# number of ions present from moles

Tags: ions, mole

I have $0.0585$ moles of $\ce{Al^{3+}}$, and need to find the number of actual ions. I thought I just divided by $6.022\times 10^{23}$ but I get $9.7\times 10^{-26}$, and the book says it should be $3.5\times 10^{22}$.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! To acquaint yourself with this page, take the [tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help). Furthermore [this tutorial](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/88/189) shows you how math and chemical formulae can be nicely formatted on this site. Hint: Think about the unit of avogadro's number $6.022\times 10^{23}$; if you divide your number of moles by avogadro's number, what unit do you get and what unit should you actually get?

Answer (score 6):

You should multiply by Avogadro's number $6.022\times 10^{23}$ instead of dividing by it. 
To make sure you always use a conversion factor (Avogadro's number is a conversion factor between moles and numbers) correctly, you need to think about units.

> Step 1 - What are the units of the answer?

You want to find the number of ions. The units of the answer is **number**.

> Step 2 - What are the units of the quantities you were given?

You were given 0.0585 moles of $\ce{Al^{3+}}$. The units you are given is "moles".

> Step 3 - What are the units of the conversion factor?

Avogadro's number (with units) is $6.022\times 10^{23} \text{ mol}^{-1}$. The units of Avogadro's number are "number per mole".

> Step 4 - Set up the problem so that units cancel and you are left with only the units you need.

**Multiplying by Avogadro's number**

$$\require{cancel} \cancel{\text{mol}}\times \dfrac{\text{number}}{\cancel{\text{mol}}}=\text{number}$$
The "moles" units cancel, leaving you with "number".

**Dividing by Avogadro's number**

$$\dfrac{\text{mol}}{\frac{\text{number}}{\text{mol}}}=\text{mol}\times \dfrac{\text{mol}}{\text{number}}=\dfrac{\text{mol}^2}{\text{number}}$$

The units do not cancel appropriately, leaving us with units that do not match the desired outcome. This approach is an application of dimensional analysis commonly called the [factor-label method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis#The_factor-label_method_for_converting_units). With practice and conscientious use of this method, you should not make unit conversion errors.

> Step 5 - Check to see if your answer makes sense.

$0.0585$ moles is about $\frac{1}{20}$ of a mole (or one half of one tenth). Your answer should be about $\frac{1}{20}$ of Avogadro's number.